# Openlayers wms returning html

Tags: html, openlayers, spatial, http-status-code-302, wms

one of our external wms service provider reroute to a 302 text/html page and the html page end up as a wms tile on our map

Are there any ways to get around this? I can't find anything in openlayers api that allows us to exclude any html response.

Thanks

Comment: Is the redirect address in the header.

Comment: Yes it is. How does that help?